# Property of a covering

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

**My problem:**

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $A=\bigcup_{i \in I}B(x_i,r_i) \subset X$ is totally bounded where $B(x,r)=\{y \in X: d(x,y)<r \}$.

I know that if $A$ is totally bounded, $A \subset \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}}B(y_j,3q_j)$ such that the balls $B(y_j,q_j)$ are mutually disjointed.

But in my notes I wrote that if $A=\bigcup_{i \in I}B(x_i,r_i)$ where $I$ is arbitrary, then we can conclude that $A=\bigcup_{i \in I}B(x_i,r_i) \subset \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} B(x_{i_n},5r_{i_n})$ such that $B(x_{i_n},r_{i_n})$ are mutually disjointed.

In other words we can use the same balls of $A$ to obtain the *covering property*.

Comment: check Vitali's Theorem in the book *Measure Theory and Fine Properties of Functions*, Evans-Gariepy